# ¿ Cual es la función del targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría comprender bien como funciona `targetSdkVersion` y como afecta *incrementar* o *disminuir* el nivel en mi proyecto android,

De antemano gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android:targetSdkVersion

Es para indicar que estas desarrollando tu aplicación usando el SDK que especificas ahí, esto no quiere decir que tu aplicación funcionará en versiones anteriores.

Para eso debes especificar el `android:minSdkVersion`, si no declaras un `targetSdkVersion` tu aplicación tomará por defecto el `android:minSdkVersion`

Answer (score 5):

En realidad necesitas saber antes las siguientes definiciones:

> [**minSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) : indica desde que API tu aplicación es
>   soportada.
>
> [**maxSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) : indica hasta que versión de API tu aplicación
>   es soportada.

Las cuales son importantes para determinar el funcionamiento de tu aplicación para definir cual es la mínima y máxima versión soportada por tu aplicación.

Ahora con respecto a :

> [**targetSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) indica con que API tu aplicación es compilada,
>   Valor entero que designa el nivel de API al cual se dirige la
>   aplicación. Si no se configura, el valor predeterminado es igual al
>   valor asignado a la minSdkVersion.
>
> Este atributo informa al sistema que has realizado las pruebas en la
>   versión prevista y el sistema no deberá habilitar ningún
>   comportamiento de compatibilidad a fin de mantener la compatibilidad
>   con versiones posteriores de tu aplicación y la versión prevista

Los 3 valores pueden ser configurados en el `AndroidManifest.xml` o en tu archivo `build.gradle`, siendo prioritaria la configuración de `build.gradle`.

A fin de mantener tu aplicación junto con cada versión de Android, debes aumentar el valor de `targetSdkVersion`  para que coincida con el nivel de API más reciente y luego probar por completo tu aplicación en la versión de la plataforma correspondiente.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: sobre "maxSdkVersion" la documentación advierte: "No se recomienda declarar este atributo. En primer lugar, no es necesario definir el atributo implementando el bloqueo de tu aplicación en versiones nuevas de la plataforma de Android a medida que se publiquen. Gracias a su diseño, las versiones nuevas de la plataforma son totalmente compatibles con versiones anteriores..."

Comment: No se esta recomendando usar maxSdkVersion, únicamente se documenta para que funciona.